# Add property to function declaration/expression inline

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have something like this:

```
const fn = function(a){
   return function(b){
       return a + b;
    }
}
```

but then imagine we want to add a property to the return function, so we do this:

```
const fn = function(a){
   const ret=  function(b){
        return a + b;
    };
   ret.foo = 'bar';
   return ret;
}
```

but what if ret is a function with a larger body and we want to return it immediately while still assigning foo to ret, so we try something like this:

```
  const fn = function(a){
       return function(b){
            return a + b;
        }.foo = 'bar';
    }
```

of course, this doesn't quite work.
I guess what I am looking for is a method on `Function.prototype` that can allow us to add a property and then return the function, something like this:

```
Function.prototype.addProp = function(prop: string, val: any){
    this[prop] = val;
    return this;
}
```

and then use that like so:

```
  const fn = function(a){
       return function(b){
            return a + b;
        }
        .addProp('foo','bar');
    }
```

Does something like this exist? Maybe I should just do it the first way.

Comment: No because that is quite useless and specific.

Comment: You don't like my stupid trick? :)

Comment: In my opinion it is not a good way of doing it. Changing the prototype for native functions is generally not worth it unless you have a very good reason of doing so.

Comment: Right I was wondering if there was some way to do this without patching `Function.prototype` which I agree is a very bad idea :)

Comment: I added an answer, I am hoping there is an altogether different way to do this, but now you know how to create a function that can inherit new props/methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is useful.( What I learned from your question is an you can make an object which can worked as a function.)  One missed thing is `Function.prototype.addProp`, it should be `Object.prototype.addProp`.

And define `Function` function which convert `function` to `Object`.
And this will return what you want.

```js
 function Function(f){
   var ret = f;
   return ret;
 }
 Object.prototype.addProp = function(prop, val){
    this[prop] = val;
    return this;
 }
    const fn = function(a){
       return Function(function(b){
            return a + b;
        }).addProp('foo','bar')
          .addProp('foo1', 'bar1');
    }
    console.log(fn(1)(2));
    console.log(fn(1).foo);
    console.log(fn(1).foo1);
```

Comment: You don't want to modify `Object.prototype` or `Function.prototype` - that is a recipe for disaster. Instead, look at my answer for how to do this right.

Answer (score 0):

So we can do this without patching `Function.prototype`, like so:

```
const proto = Object.create(Function.prototype);

proto.addProp = function(prop: string, val: any){
    this[prop] = val;
    return this;
};

const fn = function(){

};

Object.setPrototypeOf(fn, proto);
```

and so now you can call

```
fn.addProp('foo','bar');
console.log(fn.foo); // => 'bar'
```

that information is the basic way to solve the problem without modifying `Function.prototype`, but maybe there's a better way to do this with a completely different pattern.

Comment: I think this answer is a little far from your question because your quesion's most important part is `inline`

Comment: well you'd have to create a class or helper to allow you to create new functions that inherit.